# Listbox without values

Tags: asp.net, listbox

this is what happens. i don't understand why its not working, because if i copy the code to a normal template everything works fine :S so i dont think its a code issue. im working with asp and c#![enter image description here][1]

http://s21.postimg.org/3jsi8351z/weird.png here is a prints screen i took to explain the issue

Asp:

```
<asp:panel ID="pnltopico" runat="server" GroupingText="Topico" Height="100px" 
Width="550px" Visible="False" Wrap="False"> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="droptopico" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="nome" DataValueField="Id_topico" 
Height="22px" 
onselectedindexchanged="DroptopicoSelectedIndexCha nged" Width="169px">
</asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:panel ID="pnlpermissoestopico" runat="server" GroupingText="Permissões" 
Height="59px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="354px" Wrap="False" 
ClientIDMode="inherit"> 
<asp:ListBox ID="lbpermitidotp" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="true" Height="80px" 
></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnproibirtp" runat="server" onclick="BtnpermitirClick" 
Text="&gt;&gt;" /> 
<asp:Button ID="btnpermitirtp" runat="server" onclick="BtnnaopermitirClick" 
Text="&lt;&lt;" Height="26px" /> 
<asp:ListBox ID="lbproibidotp" runat="server" 
EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="true" Height="80px" onselectedindexchanged="lbproibidotp_SelectedIndex Changed" 
></asp:ListBox> </asp:panel>
```

since the code is working fine i dont think i need to post the c# code but let me know if it could help.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just Modified your code a little and Compiled it everything is working fine now:

```
<asp:panel ID="pnltopico" runat="server" GroupingText="Topico" Height="100px" 
Width="550px" Visible="False" Wrap="False"> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="droptopico" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 DataTextField="nome" DataValueField="Id_topico" 
Height="22px" 
onselectedindexchanged="droptopico_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="169px">
</asp:DropDownList> 
    </asp:panel>
<asp:panel ID="pnlpermissoestopico" runat="server" GroupingText="Permissões" 
Height="59px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="354px" Wrap="False" 
ClientIDMode="inherit"> 
<asp:ListBox ID="lbpermitidotp" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="true" Height="80px" 
>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Guest" Value="Guest" />

</asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnproibirtp" runat="server" OnClick="btnproibirtp_Click"
Text="&gt;&gt;" /> 
<asp:Button ID="btnpermitirtp" runat="server"  
Text="&lt;&lt;" Height="26px" /> 
<asp:ListBox ID="lbproibidotp" runat="server" EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="true" Height="80px">
      <asp:ListItem Text="Moderator" Value="Moderator" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Utilizer" Value="Utilizer" />
</asp:ListBox> </asp:panel>
```

and I have put the breakpoint on the Button Click of the btnproibirtp , just to verify and it works normally ,
I think u had some tags formation error or so :

```
 protected void btnproibirtp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lbl1 = lbproibidotp.SelectedValue;
    }
```

regards

Comment: thanks ill try it out, i forgot to mention im getting the data from a sql Stored Procedure, but i'll try to see if that helps

Comment: still not working anychance i have to use something diferent because of the listbox being in a panel ??